# I am not understanding, What's wrong with my code?

Tags: python

I am not understanding, what's wrong with my code? Whenever I type `hey`, `hi` or `sup`, it does not show up what I have written in the code but shows something else - what is the error I made?

Here's my code:

```
import os
import random
import time

for i in range(1, 2):

    a = random.choice(("hi, sir", "hey, sir", "hello, sir", "sup, sir", "Joe Reporting, Sir"))
    print(a)
    os.system("say '"+a+"'")


res1 = input()

if res1 is ("hi", "hey", "hello", "sup", "Hey Joe"):
    GE = ("I am Joe, Your New Personal Assintant. Nice to meet you.")
    print(GE)
    os.system("say '"+GE+"'")
else:
    js = random.choice(("okay, what would you like to do", "So, Sir What Would you like to do ", "So Sir, What to do", "k, what are we going to do"))
    print(js)
    os.system("say '"+js+"'")


User_inp = input()
print("Ok, searching")
'''
if inp  "?":
    print("Um...Let me Search")
'''
Next_inp = input()
g = random.choice(("Searching, sir", "I am on it."))
print(g)
```

Comment: `is in`, not `is`. Lookup up how to check if value in list or tuple in python

Comment: ^ this is for the line 'if res1 is ("...."):' and it's 'in' not 'is in'.. i.e if res1 in ('hi', 'hey'):

Comment: @LukeK actually `in`, not `is in`

Comment: Thanks khelwood. Should have looked up how to do it myself before jumping in!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments you have to modify your code like this.

```
res1 = input()

if res1 in ("hi", "hey", "hello", "sup", "Hey Joe"):
  GE = ("I am Joe, Your New Personal Assintant. Nice to meet you.")
  print(GE)
  os.system("say '" + GE + "'")
```

You have confused the effect of `in` and `is`; so changing `is` with `in` in your initial code solves your problem.